# Changing z-index on hover (bouncing divs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to alter [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/) to make each box come to the front when the mouse is hovering on that box.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated!

```
.bouncyHouse {
   height:200px;
   width:150%;
   background-color: black;
   position: relative;
}

.bouncer {
   position: absolute;
   width: 200px;
   color:white;
   font-size:50px;
   background-color:yellow;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(2){
   top: 30px;
   left: 100px;
   background-color:green;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(3){
   top: 50px;
   left: 200px;
   background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1zxtjgx5/

Comment: .bouncer:nth-child(3):hover{ background-color:blue; }

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the :hover psuedo class.

```
.bouncer:hover {
    z-order: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this

https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/2/

```
.bouncer:hover{
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:skyblue;
}
```

OR without change background color

https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/4/

Answer (score 2):

you can add a css `hover` for `.bouncer` to set its `z-index`

```
.bouncer:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well...

```
$('.bouncer').hover(function(){
    $('.bouncer').css({"z-index" : "9"});
    $(this).css({"z-index" : "999999"});
});
```

Add this code to your script..

Comment: I'm thinking that the only problem with that would be that CSS would be more efficient than using Javascript wouldn't it?